# For loop with Pandas DataFrames to fill list of data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm writing some code for plotting time series using a .csv file, but I have to plot for several years (2000 to 2019, to be precise) and its respective months. I tried using a for loop this way:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
c1 = pd.read_csv('D:/file.csv')
c1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(c1['Date'], format = '%m/%d/%Y')
c1.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

year = 2000

for j in range(12):
    sets = list()
    data = c1['%s-%0d'%(year, j+1)]['Moisture']
    sets.append(data)
```

I want to end up with something like this:

```
sets = [c1['2000-01']['Moisture'], c1['2000-02']['Moisture'], ... , c1['2000-12']['Moisture']]
```

So I can plot my figures with this code:

```
for j in range(12):
    sets = list()
    data = c1['%s-%0d'%(year, j+1)]['Moisture']
    sets.append(data)

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(sets[j], 'black')
    plt.title('Layer 1 (0 cm - 7 cm)')
    plt.xlabel(str(year))
    plt.ylabel(r'Moisture $(m^{3} / m^3)$')
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.savefig('D:/randomlocation.png')
```

I've tried but every time it shows

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So I think it is only adding one item to the list. How can I solve it?

Comment: Could you share an example of the DataFrame and what is the expected output?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.
In particular, we need the full error message and a trace of the offending values.

Comment: Are the values in `c1['2000-01']` dictionaries? Why do you need to use a chained assignment `c1['2000-01']['Moisture']`?

Comment: I already solved this issue with the answer below, it was just a matter of understanding well the for loop, I'm sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, you're overwriting `sets` each time the loop iterates. `sets = list()` should be moved to outside the for loop.

Also, using `i` instead of `j` here may be part of the issue

`plt.plot(sets[i], 'black')`

Comment: The `[i]` and `[j]` was a typo, my bad. Yes, it was just the overwriting issue, thank you.